Given a square binary matrix $A$ which is randomly sampled what is the probability that the rows are linearly independent
If given a square (n by n) binary matrix $A$ which is randomly sampled then what is the probability that the rows are linearly independent?
In this case we treat addition as the XOR operation.
As an example to see if the nth rows is dependent we could look at it as $$c_1a_1 \oplus ... \oplus c_{n-1}a_{n-1} = a_n$$ where $a_{i}$ represents the i-th row and $c_{i}$ can be either 0 or 1. $\oplus$ is the XOR operation above.
Would the probability be close to 1 that all rows are linearly independent?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We can rephrase the problem as follows: Of the $2^{n^2}$ $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb F_2$, how many of them are invertible? We can construct an invertible matrix by going column by column, picking a vector not in the span of the previous columns.  A $k$-dimesional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ has $2^k$ elements, and so if we have picked $k$ columns already, then we have $2^n-2^k$ valid choices for what the next column can be if we want all the rows to be linearly independent.
Putting all this together, there are $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2^n-2^{k})$ invertible matrices, and the probability that a matrix is invertible will be $(1-1/2)(1-1/4)\cdots (1-1/2^{n})$.  As n increases, this decreases and approaches a number which is approximately $0.29$.
